# Cannot conditionally make axis labels bold in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtext

I am trying to make select axis labels bold, based on a conditional from a different column. In the code below, if `Signif` equals 1, then the `Predictor` axis text should be bold. In addition, the segments should appear in the order of `Value`s  increasing value.

However, this code is not changing any of the the axis texts to bold.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtext)
library(glue)

df <- tibble(Predictor = c("Blue","Red","Green","Yellow"),
             Value = c(1,3,2,4),
             Signif = c(0,1,0,1))

df <- df %>% mutate(Predictor = ifelse(Signif==1,
                                 glue("<span style = 'font-weight:bold'>{Predictor}</span>"),
                                 glue("<span style = 'font-weight:plain'>{Predictor}</span>"))
)

df %>% 
  arrange(desc(Value)) %>% 
  mutate(Predictor=factor(Predictor, 
                          levels=df$Predictor[order(df$Value)])) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Predictor, y=Value)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend=Predictor, yend=0)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_markdown())
```

[image]

If instead I use `element_text()` in the last line, and skip the `mutate` to markdown step above:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(desc(Value)) %>% 
  mutate(Predictor=factor(Predictor, 
                          levels=df$Predictor[order(df$Value)])) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Predictor, y=Value)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend=Predictor, yend=0)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = if_else(df$Signif==1, "bold", "plain")))
```

It bolds the 2nd and 4th axis label, which corresponds to the `Signif` equals 1 in the original df.

[image]

How can I get the correct axis text labels to appear in bold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All nice answers. The deeper underlying issue however is (not exactly) "hidden" in the warning that comes when you use a vector in a theme element (see plot below).

Your original plot code would work if you would first rearrange your data frame (and re-assign it!) - see code below. I do not encourage that - ggtext::element_markdown was designed exactly with the idea in mind to avoid the use of vectors in theme.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(Predictor = c("Blue","Red","Green","Yellow"),
             Value = c(1,3,2,4),
             Signif = c(0,1,0,1))


df <- arrange(df, Predictor)
df %>% 
  arrange(desc(Value)) %>% 
  mutate(Predictor=factor(Predictor, 
                          levels=df$Predictor[order(df$Value)])) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Predictor, y=Value)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend=Predictor, yend=0)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face = if_else(df$Signif==1, "bold", "plain"))) 
#> Warning: Vectorized input to `element_text()` is not officially supported.
#> ℹ Results may be unexpected or may change in future versions of ggplot2.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: It turns out that this was actually the issue. I was using a df with multiple groups, and filtered before plotting. But it kept the order of predictors from the first group.

Answer (score 5):

I would’ve expected your code to work honestly, but you can use `<b>` instead of `<span style...>`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtext)
library(glue)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(Predictor = ifelse(Signif==1,
                            glue("<b>{Predictor}</b>"),
                            Predictor))

df %>% 
  arrange(desc(Value)) %>% 
  mutate(Predictor=factor(Predictor, 
                          levels=df$Predictor[order(df$Value)])) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Predictor, y=Value)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend=Predictor, yend=0)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_markdown())
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `ggtext` currently supports only a limited set of CSS properties. From the [docs](https://wilkelab.org/ggtext/articles/theme_elements.html)

> The CSS properties color, font-size, and font-family are currently supported.

But if you just want to have bold text the answer by @zephryl is the way to go or as a second option use markdown, i.e. wrap inside `**`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggtext)
library(glue)

df <- df %>%
  mutate(Predictor = ifelse(Signif == 1,
    glue("**{Predictor}**"),
    Predictor
  ))

df %>%
  arrange(desc(Value)) %>%
  mutate(Predictor = factor(Predictor,
    levels = df$Predictor[order(df$Value)]
  )) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Predictor, y = Value)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = Predictor, yend = 0)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_markdown())
```

[image]